# html won't display on google site

Tags: html, google-sites

With some great help from a Google Expert, I have HTML code which works perfectly when dragging the HTML file to the browser. But, I cannot get it to display properly on our Google Site. The closest I've gotten is for the search box section to display but no map. Trying to put the HTML directly onto the page won't work. iFrame wrapper won't work. Below is the HTML if anyone can help:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
    #panel {
      margin: 8px 0;
    }
    #map-canvas { width:700px; height:700px; }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var layer_0;
    function initialize() {
      geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.497533829342345, -86.4128420767679),
        zoom: 11,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
      });
      var style = [
        {
          featureType: 'all',
          elementType: 'all',
          stylers: [
            { saturation: -20 }
          ]
        }
      ];
      var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(style, {
        map: map,
        name: 'Styled Map'
      });
      map.mapTypes.set('map-style', styledMapType);
      map.setMapTypeId('map-style');
      layer_0 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
          select: "col2",
          from: "1ET-gDs1z0v1T5LVIjYEMPLLCIhLQ1IRiWhq7IMY"
        },
        map: map,
        styleId: 2,
        templateId: 2
      });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

   function codeAddress() {
      var street = document.getElementById('street').value;
      var city = document.getElementById('city').value;
      var address = street + ' ' + city + ' Indiana';
      geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    map.setZoom(15);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              position: results[0].geometry.location
          });
        } else {
          alert('Unable to locate the address');
        }
      });
   }
   </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="panel">
      <span>Enter street address:</span>
      <input id="street" type="textbox" value="501 Elm St">
      <span>City: </span>
      <select id="city">
    <option value="Paoli, Indiana">Paoli</option>
    <option value="Hardinsburg, Indiana">Hardinsburg</option>
    <option value="Orleans">Orleans</option>      <option value="Marengo">Marengo</option>      <option value="English">English</option>      <option value="Campbellsburg">Campbellsburg</option>       <option value="Livonia">Livonia</option>       <option value="French Lick">French Lick</option>
    <option value="West Baden">West Baden</option>       <option value="Orangeville">Orangeville</option>         <option value="">(Other)</option>
      </select>
      <input type="button" value="Show address" onclick="codeAddress()">
    </div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The site I where I want to display the code: https://sites.google.com/a/paoli.k12.in.us/paoli-community-school-corporation-admin/boundary - The map shown there now does not include the search feature and I was able to link it easily to my fusion table. Adding the search feature resulted in me having html code but not being able to link it to my table in the same way.

Comment: Uh, the map loads for me.  What exactly is the problem?

Comment: The map currently on the site does not have the search feature. The HTML file I have above loads fine for me if I drag it into the URL window. But, I can't get it to work on Google Site.

Answer (score 0):

You have a application with Html/ javascript

You must add this application on Google APp engine to deploy your application on Google Sites.

http://tutorialzine.com/2011/01/getting-started-with-google-app-engine/

I think , this tutorial can help you.